# Combining an imported PDB file with a set of Graphics3D objects

Tags: graphics, import, graphics3d

Imagine we import a PDB file like so (using the example from ref/format/PDB in the help directory):

```
Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=1tf6", "PDB", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

The help file says that it should be possible to treat the imported PDB image as a `Graphics3D` object, but I can't seem to get it to display with other `Graphics3D` objects after using `Import` with the specification:

```
Import["my_duplex.pdb", "Graphics3D"]
```

How would I scale and translate an imported PDB graphic and get it to display with other `Graphics3D` objects, like say a cylinder or sphere?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Axes -> True` to get an idea of the scale:

```
i = Import["ExampleData/100d.pdb", "Graphics3D"]
Show[i, Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 400]}], Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great great... can I dilate the PDB output to shrink it down?

Comment: @RVoight Try for example `s = {0, 1};
k = 1/100;
Show[i /. GraphicsComplex[a_, b__] :> GraphicsComplex[a k, b] /. 
   Sphere[a_, b_] :> Sphere[a, b k] /. 
  Cylinder[a_, b_] :> Cylinder[a, b k], Axes -> True]`